# projective space minus a closed point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-schemes, projective-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $\mathbb P^n_k=\text{Proj}(k[x_0,x_1,...,x_n])$ .

If $n\ge 2$, and $p\in \mathbb P^n_k$ is a closed point, then can $\mathbb P^n_k\setminus \{p\}$ be a Projective variety ?

Considering global section ring doesn't give any contradiction because since $\{p\}$ is a closed subset of codimension $\ge 2$, so $\mathcal O(\mathbb P^n_k\setminus \{p\})\cong \mathcal O(\mathbb P^n_k)\cong k$. Similarly, the Picard group or class group also doesn't give any contradiction.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. As any map $f:X\to Y$ with $X$ a projective variety is [closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477575/image-of-morphism-of-projective-varieties-is-projective-variety), if $\Bbb P^n_k\setminus\{p\}$ were projective, then it's image under the natural embedding in $\Bbb P^n_k$ would be closed. But it's not (if it were, $\Bbb P^n_k$ would be reducible, which is obviously nonsense).

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$