# Polynomial Maps of Real Projective Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

As a preface I don't much background in this area and I think I am dealing with older (or currently non-standard) definitions.

**Definition**: A polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is homogenous of degree $d$ if for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, f(\lambda x_1, \ldots, \lambda x_n) = \lambda^d f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

**Definition**: An ideal $I \subset \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is homogenous if it is generated by finitely many homogenous polynomials.

**Definition**: $X \subset \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a real projective variety if it is the zero locus of a prime homogenous ideal $I \subset \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

---

Now for my question, I have a $X \subset \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which is a real projective variety. I have a polynomial map $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ where $f_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are homogenous monomials of degree $d$, with $d < n$. I am interested in understanding the image $F(X)$. In particular, I care about when $F(X)$ is closed with respect to the Zariski Topology on $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$.

From reading I know that if we were working over an algebraically closed field then $F$ is a closed and hence $F(X)$ is a variety, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477575/image-of-morphism-of-projective-varieties-is-projective-variety). However, in my case we are working over $\mathbb{R}$. I cannot seem to find anything about the case when the field is not algebraically closed.

---

For more context, for a given $m$, I have matrices $(A_1, \ldots, A_m) \in \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}^{m \times M \times N})$ such that $A_i$ have rank at most $r$ (can assume $r=2$). Hence $(A_1, \ldots, A_m)$ live in a projective variety. I interested in the map

$$ (A_1, \ldots, A_m) \mapsto A_1 \odot \ldots \odot A_m$$

where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.

Answer (score 0):

In general the image of a "morphism" in real algebraic case is  [semi-algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set). However, in your case the map is (probably)finite, so proper, hence it has a closed ( in usual topology) image. So it is (probably) defined as a finite union of sets of the form $\{F_1\ge 0, \ldots F_k\ge 0\}$. Explicitely it might get very involved.

Comment: Past identifying that semi-algebraic geometry deals with this sort of problem, I don't think this is a great answer: in the usual topology, any continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is topologically proper, so it will have image closed in the usual topology. Further, because the map is semi-algebraic, the image is already a semi-algebraic set, so something like the form you write will be automatic (there is potentially some care to be taken here about viewing $\Bbb RP^n$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^N$ and picking polynomials there in order versus coordinates on $\Bbb RP^n$...).

Comment: @KReiser: Thank you for your observations!  I mentioned finite and proper because sometime the map is defined on affine varieties. Now, for projective maps I am pretty sure that the image will be a union of elementaries as described above, may be standard, but I don't have a source. Where inequalities occur they are also homogeneous of even degree. So things should be OK on the projective target.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any references to how I could compute these elementaries or determine any properties for these elementaries for my concrete map would be appreciated.

Comment: In particular, (this is not in my original question) but I am interested in how these elementaries change or don't change as I vary $m$.

Comment: @Rishi Sonthalia: No worries! I have a question about the definition: in Hadamard product you can get the product $0$, while the matrices have full rank. But then to define it from a projective space, you need it to be defined, so perhaps to land in a projective space. All in all, I think the source cannot be considered projective.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but in my setting the matrices actually cannot have $0$s. This actually comes from a data problem that I am trying to model with some math!

Comment: @Rishi Sonthalia: I see, no zeroes makes it a subset of projective space, including the image and all can be done projectively.  Certainly the case $r=1$ is simple, you get again a matrix of rank $1$. Hadamard multiplication with a matrix of rank $1$ does not change the rank. So $r=2$ is the next case, two $3\times 3$ matrices of rank $2$, what can you  say about their Hadamard product?  Interesting.